# Split Layout for frontend of application

Tags: css, angular, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I have a requirement from my client to have the frontend that should have splitting panes layout.
As shown in the image below, you can see that each of these panes can be maximized and minimized. If you're familiar with RStudio layout, then that is exactly what I am looking for. I am bit confused in what would be the best way to start. I've come across `Split.js` utility [here](https://split.js.org/#get-started) which looks good enough to start, however I am confused if it will be easy to integrate maximizing and minimizing window options to it. I am flexible in choosing Angular or React as framework. What is the best practice for building such layouts?

PS: I did quite alot of research but couldn't find any answers that were comprehensove enough.

[image]

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GoldenLayout](http://golden-layout.com/).

> This type of layout paradigm is referred to as "docker" (not to be
>   confused with the virtualisation containers). Examples for frameworks
>   that implement the docker paradigm are PhosphorJS, wcDocker or
>   dockspawn. [Reference(FAQ 1)](http://golden-layout.com/faq/)